# Hyper-V disable internal firewall

Tags: firewall, hyper-v

How can I disable a firewall on my internal network?

**Problem**

I have a Hyper-V on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with one VM, when I disable the firewall I can get internet on my VM, but when I turn on firewall, internet doesn't work. On my VM I can ping 8.8.8.8 and I can ping my gateway address too. (my server had always internet)

*Note* I try to disable internal like that but it's don't work too : http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/RRAS-Firewall-Adapter-Selection.png

I need allow some rule on my firewall with advanced.

If you need more information leave a comment, thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) What kind of internet are you using? 2) How is the host connected to the internet? 3) what type of virtual switch are you using in Hyper-V? more details will be appreciated.

Comment: My architectur is like that https://lennytech.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/clip_image004.png... My virtual switch is internal switch. Each VM have static IP 192.168.1.10 and .11 and my host is 192.168.1.254
If I set DNS on VM : 8.8.8.8 i got internet but if i set 192.168.1.254 it's don't work (and if i turn off fire wall on host it's work).. any idea?

Comment: 1) Do you have DNS installed on the host server? 2) Is the DNS port allowed on the firewall of the host server?

Comment: no dns installed, why i need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last comment, I believe that you problem is DNS, and not the firewall service.

The prove for this theory is that when you configure the VMs with the Google Public DNS servers 8.8.8.8 they work fine, but when you configure them to use the IP address 192.168.1.254 (which I can't tell if its the IP address of the host server or your gateway), name resolution fails and you don't get internet access.

You either need to fix the DNS on the gateway (if the IP address 192.168.1.254 is the gateway) or install DNS and configure it on your host server (if the IP address 192.168.1.254 is your host server)

Here's a good link on what DNS does, and how you can install and configure it inside your network: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794771